# React: Render component based on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have an input field set up so the inputs value will be console logged when a button is pressed, I am trying to render a component instead of this console.log.

I can get it to sorta work but it re-renders every time I type a single character because I'm not sure how to check for the click within the render method, I read through some of the docs but couldn't figure out how do to it. How could I go about achieving this?

here is the code

```
class Form extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        input: ''
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
   }

   handleChange(e) {
         this.setState({input: e.target.value});
   }

   handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state.input)
   }

   render() {
     //Not sure how to check for this
    if (this.state.input) {
        return <Fetch username={this.state.input} />
    }

    return(
        <form>
            <label>
                Name:
                <input type="text" value={this.state.input} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} />
        </form>          
    );
  }
 }
```

let me know if you need anymore information. Thanks!

Edit: By the way, I want to be able to submit the form many times, sorry, I should have been more descriptive of my problem. I want the Form component to stay rendered and I want the Fetch component to get rendered on clicked

Comment: What you are trying to do is to display the Fetch component when the user click on submit button right ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution depends on your needs and there might be a lot of them. The simplest way, just to demonstrate:

```js
class Form extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        input: '',
        submitted: false,  // adding the flag
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
   }

   handleChange(e) {
         this.setState({input: e.target.value});
   }

   handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ submitted: true });  // set the flag on submit
        console.log(this.state.input)
   }

   render() {
     //Not sure how to check for this
    if (this.state.submitted) {  // show the component by the flag
        return <Fetch username={this.state.input} />
    }

    return(
        <form>
            <label>
                Name:
                <input type="text" value={this.state.input} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} />
        </form>          
    );
  }
}
```

Obviously, in real application it's too simple logic. You have to define first, what are you trying to reach.

**UPDATE:**

If you want to keep the input field and the component simultaneously, you can do it like this:

```js
class Form extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        input: '',
        submitted: false,  // adding the flag
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
   }

   handleChange(e) {
         this.setState({input: e.target.value});
   }

   handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ submitted: true });  // set the flag on submit
        console.log(this.state.input)
   }

   render() {
    return(
        <form>
            <label>
                Name:
                <input type="text" value={this.state.input} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} />

            {this.state.submitted && (
              <Fetch username={this.state.input} />
            )}
        </form>          
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked great for a single submit. But yeah I should have been more descriptive with my use case. I want to be able to submit the form many times. It's a github API lookup btw, so Im trying to display the profile info on click and I want the Form component to stay rendered after you load the profile.

Comment: I just returned the Form and Fetch components from the conditional within the render and it works as I want! Didn't know you could return a component from with in itself! Never know till you try I guess. Thanks for the help again.

Comment: It keeps rendering a new Fetch component every time I click the button. How can I delete the old one when I submit for a second etc? I only ever want 1 Fetch component rendered. Is there an easy way to clean up like unmount() or something?

Comment: Have you seen my update? It renders only one `Fetch` component with the `username` from the state.

Comment: This works great, thanks a lot! Sorry for not being clear from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you are doing is every time the user type a character, you are displaying Fetch component with the input's value passed in props.

With this and with the handleChange method

```
if (this.state.input) {
        return <Fetch username={this.state.input} />
    }
```

The condition here return true if input is different from "". So when a character is type it becomes true and displays it.

In your case what you want to do is to display the Fetch component when you are clicking on the submit button.
What you can do is create a state to manage it.

For example you could have this in your state :

```
this.state = {
        input: '',
        fetchIsVisibile: false,
    };
```

Then in your handleSubmit just do this:

```
handleSubmit(e) {
        this.setState({ fetchIsVisible: true }),;
        e.preventDefault();
   }
```

And the condition for display your fetch component would be using this new state instead of input state

```
if (this.state.fetchIsVisible) {
        return <Fetch username={this.state.input} />
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add state whether the form is submitted in the state and to check for it when rendering the component

if you want to check whether the form is submitted and the input is not empty you can use `(this.state.submitted && this.state.input)` instead

```js
class Form extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        input: '',
        submitted: false
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
   }

   handleChange(e) {
         this.setState({input: e.target.value});
   }

   handleSubmit(e) {
        this.setState({
          submitted: true
        });
   }

   render() {
     //Not sure how to check for this
    if (this.state.submitted) {
        return <div>
          <div>FETCH COMPONENT</div>
          <div>input: {this.state.input}</div>
        </div>
    }

    return(
        <form>
            <label>
                Name:
                <input type="text" value={this.state.input} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </label>
            <div>input: {this.state.input}</div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} />
        </form>          
    );
  }
 }
 
 ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```